# Chest contents leveling

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

Are the contents of chests in The Elder Scrolls Blades set at the time they are obtained, or are the contents set at the time they are opened?

I have heard of people hoarding gold chests until they are higher levels, with the assumption that they will get higher level rewards, but I’m not sure if that is actually the case.